# Xcode 10 Storyboard extremely slow to the point of unresponsive

Tags: ios, xcode

my Xcode 8.3.3 storyboard is extremely slow almost unresponsive and I don't know what is causing it.

Tried:

Deleting xcuserdata and opening Xcode again.

Opening Xcode on a different project. (It worked fine. It just seems to be this one main.storyboard in this specific project.)

Extracting the main.storyboard file and opening and closing Xcode then putting it back in.

Restarting my Mac (Late 2016. Refurbished with touch-bar. 16GB memory 512GB storage.)

Cleaning the project. (CMD+Shift+K)

All of these have failed and I'm trying to launch my app next week. If this persists, I won't be able to launch and will get behind my schedule.

When I deleted the xcuserdata, I was able to navigate to another .swift file and it works fine. But when I go into storyboard it slows down to basically 1FPS. (I have a MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM I don't know why it isn't handling this better.)

I'm really fed up with this and all the other things I have tried didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to split your storyboard up to smaller storyboards and link them with Storyboard References?

Comment: Is this with one specific project ? or is it happening with all other projects too?

Comment: just this one project and i cant split the storyboard because its being so damn slow and if it helps it started right after i added a button to a viewcontroller then left to do some things

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found the anwser to my own question for anyone who is having this issue.

1. clear your `xcuserdata` and `xcworkspace` from your Xcode project by clicking *show package contents* on your `xcodeproj` file. Move `xcuserdata` and `xcworkspace` to the trash.
2. This allows you to open up your Xcode project again and be able to open storyboard as source code. It resets the last file you had open. To do this right-click (or two-finger click on track-pad) on `main.storyboard` and choose *Open as Source Code*
3. At the top you'll see some code similar or identical to this

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12121" systemVersion="16G29" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="OjV-iF-7f7">
<device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait">
    <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
</device>
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12089"/>
/* delete this here */
<capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<customFonts key="customFonts">
    <array key="small_pixel.ttf">
        <string>Small-Pixel</string>
    </array>
</customFonts>
<scenes>
```

Don't panic, you are only looking for one line. No editing needs to be done.

```
<capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/"
```

4. Once you've found it, delete the entire line from the code.

You should now be able to open up the main.storyboard file as the normal interface builder by right-clicking (two-finger click on track-pad) and choosing *Open as Interface Builder*

(01/07/2020) Reports state this still works for the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: I was seeing extremely slow updates to storyboards in Xcode 9.1, and tried step 4. When I went back to the storyboard, everything was working much better! When I went back to the source, the capability was added back! I'm wondering if the trick is just opening the storyboard in code then going back to IB?

Comment: I honestly dont know why it happens im just glad I was able to find a way to fix it because I had a deadline and it was messing me up

Comment: In Xcode 9.3 i tried all this, but stil it is very slow when moving to storyboard from classes and vice versa.

Comment: So the update from 9.2 to 9.3 changed a whole tonne of things. I would recommend asking this as a new question.

Comment: Worked for me in 9.3

Comment: Great!! Solution Work for me...@E. Huckabee

Comment: you are my hero, I was so close to throwing the mac out of the window!

Comment: i deleted the line, cleaned the build, built it again. changed a label title, built again (2 minutes every time), opened again in "source code", and the "documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" line came back! why? :-( (xcode 11)

Comment: This worked for me but when I created a new xib file this line comes with it. I want to disable it. How can I disable does anyone know?

Comment: I don’t think you need to mess with the `xcuserdata` and `xcworkspace` files. Deleting the capability line in a text editor (while the project is _not_ open in Xcode) should suffice.

Comment: I have the same problem after updating to Xcode 12. Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me :(

Comment: Love you! Cheers to you.

Comment: Step 4 was the winner for me :)

Comment: after delete, the line still come back again.

Comment: This also worked for Xcode 13.2

Comment: My storyboard was extremely slow. When clicking on a VC, it would take you 10 minutes or so to complete the action. Plus, all VCs somehow turned into black screens. This answer just worked and saved me from this madness.

Answer (score 8):

I had extremely slow only when editing on xib file in Xcode version 10.1. What worked for me was to disable the Source Control under Xcode/Preferences/Source Control and then I checked "Enable Source Control" again and it fixed it.

Comment: Worked for me when a project slowed down in Xcode 11.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on xcode 10.1 then i changed the project format from **Xcode 8.0 - compatible**
 to 
**Xcode 9.3 - compatible** and everything it's working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has a dual Graphics card, you can install a GFXCardStatus or otherwise switch to an integrated video card. After this manipulation, the storyboard worked very well for me. Good luck!

https://github.com/steveschow/gfxCardStatus/releases/tag/v2.4.4i

[image]